# Opencart 1.5.4 addToCart() first time page shows function does not work

Tags: php, javascript, opencart

I am currently working on a project in Open Cart 1.5.4. I slighty moved the cart into another div without any problems. The thing is on new computers and first time they enter the site it´s not possible for the customer to add a product to cart. If they go into another page and then back it works just fine. The javascript file is loaded properly without any problems.

Hope this explanation explains the problem or bug pretty good.

Thanks in advance.

JAVASCRIPT

```
function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                //$('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');
                try {
                    $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
                }
                catch(err) {
                    console.log(err.message());
                }

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

                $(".heading").animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 'slow');

                $(".cart_arrow").attr("style", "display: block;");

                $(".heading").animate({backgroundColor: "#585858"}, 'slow');

            }   
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem. When Open Cart is installed and domain is about to be choosen, you can choose www or non-www. Depends on the one you choose the other wont work.
So the solution to the problem htaccess redirect for this one from non-www to www adress

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The redirect has to be over RewriteBase /

Thanks and I hope this helps in the future for anyone nedded this kind of support

Answer (score 0):

change

```
url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
```

to

```
url: $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it was not really the cause of the problem, recently found the problem and it was the non-www domain adress which I throw in a htaccess file